# The Problem of Multiple Threads for Sqlite3 - got an unexpected result

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

i try to test wirting/reading data into sqlite database by using multiple threads.

Sometimes it doesn't seem to get the right result. Is that BUG?

i make two files to test it. the first one is **test.py**.

```py
import threading
import master

def add():
    for i in range(10):
        num = master.get()
        tmp = num + 1
        master.update(tmp)
        print(f"add: {i}, {num}")


def sub():
    for i in range(10):
        num = master.get()
        tmp = num - 1
        master.update(tmp)
        print(f"sub: {i}, {num}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subThread01 = threading.Thread(target=add)
    subThread02 = threading.Thread(target=sub)
    subThread01.start()
    subThread02.start()
    subThread01.join()
    subThread02.join()
    print(master.get())
```

the second file is **master.py**.

```py
import sqlite3
import threading

lock = threading.Lock()

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()

# creat table
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info ( userid INT PRIMARY KEY, data INT );""")
conn.commit()

# insert init data
db = (0, 0)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO info VALUES(?, ?);", db)
conn.commit()

# update data
def update(num):
    with lock:
        db = (num, 0)
        cur.execute("UPDATE info set data = ? where userid = ?;", db)
        conn.commit()

# get data
def get():
    with lock:
        cur.execute(f"SELECT data FROM info where userid = 0;")
        result = cur.fetchone()
        return result[0]
```

the result I expected was 0 when i run the `test.py`. but the actual result is random, sometimes -3, sometimes 9, etc.

Where does the problem lie?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`update` and `get` functions are `thread-safe` but `add` and `sub` functions are not. This will create synchronization problems. You should also do thread-safe your `add` and `sub` functions like ;

```
def add():
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            num = master.get()
            tmp = num + 1
            master.update(tmp)
            print(f"add: {i}, {num}")


def sub():
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            num = master.get()
            tmp = num - 1
            master.update(tmp)
            print(f"sub: {i}, {num}")
```

Edit:
My answer is missing, I forgot to specify a new lock object. It should be like:

```
import threading
import master

lock=threading.Lock()

def add():
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            num = master.get()
            tmp = num + 1
            master.update(tmp)
            print(f"add: {i}, {num}")


def sub():
    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            num = master.get()
            tmp = num - 1
            master.update(tmp)
            print(f"sub: {i}, {num}")
```

Edit 2 (As an answer to OP's comment):

Let's examine, (please read comments in the `add` func)

```
def add():
    for i in range(10):
        num = master.get() # let's say num==0
        tmp = num + 1 
        """
        Now tmp==1. And think that, GIL released and OS switch to subThread02.
        When switching, i==0 this is where we left
        """
        master.update(tmp)
```

continue with subThread02;

```
def sub():
    for i in range(10):
        num = master.get()
        tmp = num - 1
        master.update(tmp)
```

Think that, GIL not released and for loop finished(Without any Interrupt). last operation will be `master.update(-10)`

After the last operation, [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython) will released and then Operating System switch to subThread01.

In `add` function, we will continue where we leave, In `add` function,  `master.update(0)`(**Attention please**) will be evaluated and then for loop will iterate 9 times and lastly it will do master.update(10). So synchronization problem will occur and `print(master.get())` will show you 10, but result can be vary maybe 5 or -3 or maybe 0

Also you saying that "I removed `sqlite` and set a variable and then I tested it, there is no any synchronization problems" I will want to you change this `for i in range(100):` to `for i in range(100000):` in both threads.(Because `for i in range(100):` loop finished immediately without any interruption and you will see correct result, but this is not guarantee, interrupts can happen anytime) Then you will see wrong results (Please run it more than one to see wrong result).

Please look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-python-set-2-synchronization/) also.

Comment: If you do this then master.get() won't run because it won't be able to acquire the lock

Comment: @Vlad, Yes you right because there is no lock object and it will throw NameError exception, I forgot to paste this: lock=threading.lock(). I edited my answer

Comment: i know this way can work properly. but i am curious why the result is unexpected when doesn't use this way. because i already make a lock in master.py. in fact, if i don't use sqlite3 module, just set a number variable to testing, it will work properly. i don't need to make the other lock in test.py.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you're right. if i don't use sqlite3 module, it will still show unexcepted result sometimes. in the testing proccess, i finally found a way that no need to make the other lock in test.py, just make the add/sup function in master.py, and use "threading.Thread(target=master.add)" in test.py will work properly.

Comment: @Brian, You're welcome, you can modify your project according to your case. Multithreading is usefull, but it needs very attention

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a feature, not a bug.

For the result to be 0, both threads would have to be scheduled for running *exactly* in sequence.
And if you had only two threads, that might work.

However there is at third thread (the main thread).
Without extra measures, there is no way to tell which thread will be selected for running after that.

You could however use e.g. a [`Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) instead of a `Lock` to enforce the threads running one after another.